# C# Assignment of Variables in groups

Tags: c#, .net

What C# feature (if any) allows you to write code like this:
`(a, b, c) = (3, 4, 5);`

Comment: Looks like tuple destructuring? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct

Comment: Why you asking?

Comment: @GrantWinney, and downvoting a valid question. I saw the syntax in code, and wanted to understand its origins in the specification.

Comment: @GrantWinney I agree and it's my comment. I'm very happy to be enlightened with a feature I was not aware of.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is the new tuple syntax introduced in C# 7.

You will need to declare the variables first, unless that statement is written with `var` in front, so either of these will work:

```
var (a, b, c) = (3, 4, 5);
```

or:

```
int a, b, c;
(a, b, c) = (3, 4, 5);
```

Both of these will be equivalent to:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
int c = 5;
```

Note that this does not construct a *tuple*, it uses the new tuple *syntax* that C# 7 got so the compiled IL is actually identical to that last piece of code above (scroll down for proof of this.)

Tuples were added to the .NET Framework 4.7.1 and .NET Core 2.1 (I think), or through a nuget package if you're on an older .NET Framework/Core/Standard version.

However, new syntax and the **concept** of tuples was also added into C#, both as a fancy syntax to construct instances of these tuple *types* but **also as a core concept in the C# language**.

For instance, to swap the contents of two variables (of the same type) you can now use this syntax:

```
(x, y) = (y, x);
```

This does not construct a new tuple instance and is functionally identical to this:

```
var temp = x;
x = y;
y = x;
```

although here the compiler can benefit from having access to IL instructions which it is hard to write C# code for. The above swap (with the tuple syntax) gets compiled to this:

```
ldarg.2
ldarg.1
starg.s 02 // store v1 into v2
starg.s 01 // store v2 into v1
```

---

To show that the two pieces of code I mentioned earlier **really are identical**, I executed the following piece of code in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) and then examined the IL which LINQPad can show, I've put the two methods side by side so you can see the similarities:

```
public void Test1()
{
    int a, b, c;
    (a, b, c) = (3, 4, 5);

    a.Dump();
    b.Dump();
    c.Dump();
}

public void Test2()
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    int c = 5;

    a.Dump();
    b.Dump();
    c.Dump();
}
```

IL Output:

```
Test1:                                                           Test2:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.3                                               IL_0000:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.4                                               IL_0001:  ldc.i4.4    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // b                                       IL_0002:  stloc.0     // b
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.5                                               IL_0003:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0004:  stloc.1     // c                                       IL_0004:  stloc.1     // c
IL_0005:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump<Int32>             IL_0005:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump<Int32>
IL_000A:  pop                                                    IL_000A:  pop         
IL_000B:  ldloc.0     // b                                       IL_000B:  ldloc.0     // b
IL_000C:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump<Int32>             IL_000C:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump<Int32>
IL_0011:  pop                                                    IL_0011:  pop         
IL_0012:  ldloc.1     // c                                       IL_0012:  ldloc.1     // c
IL_0013:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump<Int32>             IL_0013:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump<Int32>
IL_0018:  pop                                                    IL_0018:  pop         
IL_0019:  ret                                                    IL_0019:  ret
```

Comment: It took a while to realize that the "tuple" is none. You can't access it as a group as you could with `var namedTuples = (a: 3, b: 4, c: 5)`. So what is the benefit of this syntax? Just that you only need one line?

Comment: If the concept lends itself to the use of this syntax, like things that go together even though they are separate variables. For instance, `(x, y) = (0, 0);` to assign a point when you have distinct variables for the dimensions. I probably wouldn't use this syntax for anything but this kind of situation though but it *is* legal syntax.

Comment: No, as you say, there isn't a tuple **in play** here, the tuple *syntax* allows a different syntax for assigning values to multiple variables as one statement, but as I said, I probably wouldn't use this particular syntax for anything but the most specific cases.

Comment: This just strengthens my resolve to create the video I've been planning on creating, I want to make a video about all things tuples in C# 7, including some of the things mentioned in this answer as I suspect not everyone is aware that the tuple syntax in C# 7 can do a lot more than just construct tuples.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen you went over and above with this answer. Thanks! I just wanted to make sure it's valid in the C# specification and not just something that works. Anyway, it makes code neater. Also, both the use and concept behind it bring give more functional programming style flavour to C#

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, could you please point me to an official doc regarding the swap scenario you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: I have a hard time finding official documentation for any of the new stuff because it's spread over various github discussions, forum posts, blog posts, etc. I hope they create a new and proper C# specification soon. I'll see what I can find.

Comment: I cannot find anything useful, I've made an issue on GitHub - [#1656: Official documentation/specification of C# "swap" syntax with tuples?](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1656), if something comes back I'll add a comment with it.

Comment: I've found a *question* related to this - [Deconstructing assignments](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/0709623617764880198f972d66845e88a89fe149/meetings/2016/LDM-2016-04-12-22.md#deconstructing-assignments), it doesn't feel like "official specification" though so I'll keep searching.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's important not to use unintended yet parsable syntactic/semantic constructs, from a security point of view.

Comment: I highly doubt it is unintended though, they could've easily simply compiled this using existing official syntax, such as deconstruction, so this: `(x, y) = (y, x);` could've easily been translated to `new ValueTuple<T1, T2>(y, x).Deconstruct(out x, out y);`, but they didn't.

Comment: I got a [reply on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1656#issuecomment-399433482) linking to [Deconstruction](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/deconstruction.md) stating: "But in the special case where the expression on the right-hand-side is a tuple (tuple expression or tuple type), then the elements of the tuple are assigned to the variables on the left-hand-side without calling Deconstruct.". So I guess this makes it official.

Answer (score 0):

You may assign value in 3 ways what you want is basically works in python not in c#

First one

```
int a,b,c;// and so on.
a=b=c=1;
```

Another way

```
int a=1,b=2,c=3;
```

or you may refer tuple

```
var (a, b, c) = (3, 4, 5);
```